# Adding Facebook Messenger channel trigger a JS bug in the "My Bots" page

Tags: botframework

I've tried to add a Facebook Messenger channel to one of my bots. I've entered e app/page ID, app secret and page token of my FB app and page (that, BTW, I use in another bot). 
Everything checked out: after hitting "Resubmit" in https://facebook.botframework.com/Dev, I got the success message

> Credentials have been validated.

However, when clicking on

> "I'm done configuring Facebook Messenger"

button and going back to [my bot page](https://dev.botframework.com/bots?id=%3CMy%20Bot%20ID%3E), everything between the Bot Framework Preview and the 'contact us' footer is gone.

I did some debugging and found that in *all.js?v=121* the code should be updated to `if (aa && aa.length>0)` to account for HtmlLink without `<a>` tag.

Any ideas if there are workarounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem two days ago, but have since resolved it.  If it's not resolved for you, let us know as your scenario might be different.